# Remove front part of string using array of removal options

Tags: php, arrays

Given:

- An array of model numbers i.e `(30, 50, 55, 85, 120)`
- a single string that contains model number that is guaranteed to be in the array, immediately followed by a submodel number.  Submodel can be a number between 1 and 50.
- Examples: `12022`, `502`, `55123`

Wanted:

- a single output string containing just the submodel number, i.e `22`, `2`, `123`
- aka the front part of string that was in array is removed
- Examples:  `12022` => `22`, `1202` => `2`, `502` => `2`, `55123` => `123`, `5050` => `50`

I can think of various ways to do this, but looking for something concise.  Bonus if it's also aesthetically beautiful :)

Comment: Could you post your attempts please?...

Comment: Will you ever have (for example) both `12` and `120` in your modelnumbers array? If yes, which should be removed?

Comment: posted attempt as answer.. + it is possible that ambiguity will be present in the array.  If so, it is okay to fail (i.e throw an exception).  Or just remove the first match and return that.

Comment: Are you definitely working with strings? Your examples look like integers which would allow some interesting solutions.

Comment: they can be integers, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $arr = array(30, 50, 55, 85, 120); // Array of forbiddens
    $str = "12022, 502, 55123"; // Your string
    $sep = array_map('trim', explode(",", $str));
    foreach($sep as $key => $value)
        foreach ($arr as $sec)
            if(preg_match("@^$sec@", $value))
                $sep[$key] = substr($value, strlen($sec));
    print_r($sep);
```

***Output***:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 22
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 123
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```
$v = array(120, 50, 55);
print removeModel("502", $v);

function removeModel($str, $v)
{
    foreach($v as $value)
        if (preg_match("/^$value/",$str))
            return preg_replace("/$value/", "", $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substr($yourString, $x)` function to cut first `$x` characters from `$yourString`.

My idea:

```
    <?php
    $str = "502"; //or "12022" for testing
    if(strlen($str)==3) 
        $newStr=substr($str, (strlen($str)-1)); //502 -> 2
    else
        $newStr=substr($str, (strlen($str)-2)); //12022 -> 22
    echo ltrim($newStr, '0');
    ?>
```

Comment: that might work.. I think that begins to depend more and more on what the numbers are.  i.e. it is possible that we will have `1202` (answer "2") and `5022` (answer "22"), so that code will fail.  Because the $submodel number is usually one or 2 chars

Comment: Updated. I didn't understand very well what you have to do with those strings, so I wrote the code strictly considering your example...

Comment: I can also have numbers like "1202" and "12022", where "120" is the model number, and "2", or "22" is the submodel.  Model number is what's in array.  Submodel can be between 1 and 50 or so.

Comment: Updated again. Used ltrim() to remove the zeros from the beggining of the string.

Answer (score -4):

just loop the array and replace in the string every array value to empty string

Comment: That wouldn't work, what if one of the strings is 30155?

Comment: So that would break the request to "Remove the front part of the string if it exists in the array" as your suggestion just removed the front AND back.